# javascript dynamic checkbox checking

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a form (id="myForm") whose checkbox ("checkbox") I check/uncheck as follows:

```
document.forms['myForm'].checkbox.checked = false;
```

How can I do this dynamically? I.e. have a function where I pass in the name of the checkbox and then check or uncheck it?

```
function check(name) {
  document.forms['myForm'].**name**.checked = false; // how can I do this right?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, `foo.bar` is equivalent to `foo["bar"]`, thus you can use:

```
document.forms['myForm'][checkboxName].checked = false;
```

However, it is more direct if you can give each checkbox a unique `id`, and use

```
document.getElementById(checkboxId).checked = false;
```

Comment: thanks this works. just curious: what happens if 'myForm' does not have a checkbox with the passed in checkboxName?  Will it fail silently?

Comment: if `checkboxName` doesn't exist on form it will fail and throw a JS error. You should put some error checking in before setting the `checked` flag.

Comment: @aeq: It won't be silent. You could check with `var cb = document.forms['myForm'][checkboxName]; if (cb) { cb.checked=false; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple function like this and pass in the `ID` of the checkbox and the resulting state whether or not the checkbox should be checked.

```
function checkTheBox(id, checkState)
{
    var checkbox = document.getElementById(id);
    if(checkbox) 
        checkbox.checked = checkState;
}
```

This sample also includes some error checking to ensure that the checkbox exists before attempting to set the `checked` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
function checkuncheck(formName, checkName, status)
{
  document.forms[formName][checkName].checked = status;
}
```

Where you pass `status` as either `true` to make it checked or `false` to make it unchecked.

Comment: That will look for a property named `formName` (literally) on the `document` object, not for the actual value that the variable has, you should use the bracket notation `document.forms[formName]` as KennyTM suggest.

Comment: You're welcome, the same applies to `checkName`, I would do: `document.forms[formName].elements[checkName].checked = status;`

Comment: @CMS: Yes updated with that before your comment, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.forms['myForm'].**name**.defaultChecked = true;
```